# Update a table row with the result of an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that includes one table row and its contents...

```
@{string divid = "lostbusiness_" + Model.lostid;}
<tr id="@divid">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        "UpdateLostBusiness",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "lostbusinessupdated"
        }))
        {
        <td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function lostbusinessupdated(result) {

                    $("#@divid").html(result);
                }
            </script>
            @Html.Hidden("lostid", Model.lostid)
            @Html.Hidden("bookingid", Model.bookingid)

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
                    "DeleteLostBusiness", new { lostid = Model.lostid },
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        Confirm = "Delete?",
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        OnSuccess = "postmessage('lostbusiness_Deleted_" + Model.lostid + "')"
                    })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.lost_code, (SelectList)ViewBag.ddllostcodes, "--Select Users--")

        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("lost_reason", Model.lost_reason)<input type="submit" value="update" /></td>



    }
</tr>
```

The above partial view is returned to the main view upon successful ajax call.
I don't know where to insert the result though. Because the partial view includes the table row, the table row is duplicated, so the resulting html includes nested table rows with the same id.

I would move the table row opening and closing tags outside of the partial view, but this causes problems with the insert ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the JQuery method `replaceWith()` [(JQuery replaceWith docs)](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

*"Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed."*
So:

```
$("#@divid").replaceWith(result);
```